# OnClick Java Script Button Throwing Unexpected Identifier Error

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I am a novice to creating onclick javascript buttons so please forgive my ignorance. I am creating a button that will flag the field SOW_Needed__c on the custom object Project_Request_Form__c. I was able to get this code from forums however I cannot get it to work. I get an error "Unexpected Identifier Error". I have tried to sift through the many posts about this same issue however I simply cannot understand why it doesn't work. Here is my code below, any help is appreciated.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js")}

     if({!Project_Request_Form__c.SOW_Needed__c} == false)
     {
          var c = new sforce.SObject("Project_Request_Form__c");
          c.id = "{!Project_Request_Form__c.Id}";
          c.SOW_Needed__c = true;
          result = sforce.connection.update([c]);
          if ( result[0].getBoolean( "success" ) )
          {
               window.location.reload();
          }
          else
          {
               alert( result[0].errors.message);
          }
     }
     else
     {
          alert("Already True");
     }
```

Comment: I think c.id must be c.Id JavaScript case sensitive right.

Comment: if you are getting this error-> "Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token =="  then try using quotes in your If statement as Eric's code. '{!Project_Request_Form__c.SOW_Needed__c}' .

Answer (score 2):

I could not find a specific issue with your code. I copied and pasted into my org and it works as expected....

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js")}

     if('{!Account.Active__c}' != 'Yes')
     {
          var c = new sforce.SObject("Account");
          c.id = "{!Account.Id}";
          c.Active__c = true;
          result = sforce.connection.update([c]);
          if ( result[0].getBoolean( "success" ) )
          {
               window.location.reload();
          }
          else
          {
               alert( result[0].errors.message);
          }

     }
     else
     {
          alert("Already True");
     }
```

I did not make any modification except to change the Object and field name to one in my org. **Note** Active__c is a picklist in this case not a boolean

I even left the lowercase id and the mixed " and ' as well as the non declared var `result`

Maybe try with the above using standard fields then verify it works. Once you have it working with standard fields, start adding in your custom fields and see if it breaks.

Another way is to remove all lines of code and add them back in one by one until they break. Once they break, alert the value just before and you should be able to see what is going on.

While not an ideal way to test, the code is short enough that it is completely feasible.

Comment: i think error is at his IF statment. he didnot use quotes  if({!Project_Request_Form__c.SOW_Needed__c} == false) .

Comment: You don't need to for a Boolean

Comment: {!Project_Request_Form__c.SOW_Needed__c} im talikng about this

Comment: Yea, it evaluates to a Boolean

Comment: i think we get this error Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token == i just tried

Comment: I'll verify when I get home too then. It should not as it evaluates to false == false. But u may be right. Even if so it's a different error than the op posted which says that line was ok in their code

Comment: Yea op posted Unexpected Identifier Error.  Must be something else.

Comment: @blackPerlSAF - I just tried this and it works just fine `if({! Account.Test_Check__c } == false) ` - If the field you are using is not a checkbox field you have to wrap in the quotes, otherwise no quotes. If you do wrap a boolean in quotes though you would have to do both like this `if("{! Account.Test_Check__c }" == "false") `

Comment: OK my field was picklist value

Comment: When doing comparisons, I usually prefer to evaluate inside the merge field. In your example, `if( {!IsPickVal(Account.Active__c, 'Yes')} )` is how I'd write it; it will evaluate to either `if( true )` or `if( false )`. Not that there's anything wrong with your way, I just thing it's easier to read.

Comment: Yea I truly believe that is the currect way @sfdcfox. I just tried what OP had done, just to figure out the error.

Comment: Hey everyone,  first let me just just say thank you for all the response, it's great  to see how helpful everyone is. I was able to get it to work but updating "c.id" to "c.Id".